# Does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'ReturnsExtension'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

Not able to call this function `Validate()`

getting error cs1929 Isetup<IserviceTemplateblService, Task>'does not contain defination for 'ReturnsAsync'and best extension method overload
The original code from controller:

```
 (byte[] fc, string fe, Sheet sheet, Errors errors) = await serviceTemplateblService.Validate(uploadRequest);
```

when I try to mock this method I write the code as below

```
mOckServiceTemplateblService.Setup(x=>x.Validate(It.IsAny<ServiceUploadRequest>())).
ReturnsAsync(fileContent,logicSheet, new Error());
```

I am getting line error as I mentioned above. Please give me suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what the problem is because there's no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but as posted, `Validate` returns a quadruple (four-tuple).

The attempted `ReturnsAsync` call, however, only defines three values (a triple, or three-tuple). Set it up so that it returns all four values, and remember to surround them with brackets `(val1, val2, val3, val4)` in order to indicate a tuple - so:

```
ReturnsAsync((val1, val2, val3, val4));
```

Comment: Great thing! nice catch

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns a `Task<(byte[],Sheet,string,Errors)>`. The round braces indicate that it is a value tuple. You also have to give these braces at `ReturnsAsync`:

```
mOckServiceTemplateblService.Setup(x=>x.Validate(It.IsAny<ServiceUploadRequest>())).
ReturnsAsync((fileContent,"",logicSheet, new Errors()));
```

Also note that you forgot the second value of the tuple. As an example, I inserted an empty string.